# Constrainting layout to not go out of bounds with Positioned widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-positioned

I am currently working on a layout that displays a `Positioned` widget on the entire screen.
It's positioning itself close to the detected barcode, Look at the image below for an example.

[image: UI example]

But when the barcode moves to close the the left edge of the screen, the UI elements are drawn partially offscreen. Is there a way I can fix this without having to calculate when I am going out of bounds each frame?

[image: Overflow example]

Here is the code that I use to set this up:

```dart
Widget _buildImage() {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      child: _controller == null
          ? const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Initializing Camera...',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                CameraPreview(_controller!),
                _buildResults(),
                if (_scanResults.isNotEmpty)
                   _buildUIElements()

              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUIElements() {
    Barcode barcode = _scanResults[0];
    final Size imageSize = Size(
      _controller!.value.previewSize!.height,
      _controller!.value.previewSize!.width,
    );
    var boundingBox = barcode.boundingBox!;
    var rect = scaleRect(rect: boundingBox, imageSize: imageSize, widgetSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      top: rect.bottom,
      left: rect.left,
      child: Card(
        child: Text('This is an amaizing product'),
      ),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
  }
```

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

> Don't mind the excessive use of `!` still learning the whole null-safety thing :)

EDIT 1:
As suggested by pskink I have looked at how the tooltips in flutter work and made use of the `SingleChildLayoutDelegate` in combination with a `CustomSingleChildLayout` and this works perfectly for tracking the position but now there is no option to animate this.

My delegate class is as follows:

```dart
class CustomSingleChildDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {

  CustomSingleChildDelegate ({
    required this.target,
    required this.verticalOffset,
    required this.preferBelow,
  });

  final Offset target;

  final double verticalOffset;

  final bool preferBelow;

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) => constraints.loosen();

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    return positionDependentBox(
      size: size,
      childSize: childSize,
      target: target,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      preferBelow: preferBelow,

    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(CustomSingleChildDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return target != oldDelegate.target
        || verticalOffset != oldDelegate.verticalOffset
        || preferBelow != oldDelegate.preferBelow;
  }
}
```

And then updated my builder function with:

```dart
return CustomSingleChildLayout(
        delegate: CustomSingleChildDelegate (target: rect.bottomCenter, verticalOffset: 20, preferBelow: true),
        child: Card(
            child: Text('This is an amaizing product'),
          ),
      )
```

Having the `AnimatedPositioned` as child of the layout causes an exception.

Comment: check `tooltip.dart` source code - [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tooltip.dart#L517) delegate class in particular - it uses `positionDependentBox` function that "Position a child box within a container box, either above or below a target point."

Comment: Ah right! Let me check that, thanks for the tip. I'll update this post if I find the solution

Comment: Yeah I am currently trying to use implicit animations, but for some reason the animation is very choppy.

Comment: No that works fine, but now I just need to make sure that I set the state correctly for these floating UI elements